# Overleaf Why PDF Rendering Error for any projects?

Tags: errors, overleaf, compilation-error

I am facing the issue of PDF Rendering Error for basically any projects I am making in Overleaf, including blank proejcts. This is the source code I am using:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{Economics-Data-0.1}
\author{Imran Farid}
\date{June 2022}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

But Overleaf responds with a PDF Rendering Error. And the raw log shows this:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.23 (TeX Live 2021) (preloaded format=pdflatex 

2021.9.30)  19 JUN 2022 04:32
entering extended mode
 \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**main.tex
(./main.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-06-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2021-07-12> (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/02/12 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2021/02/12 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count182
\c@section=\count183
\c@subsection=\count184
\c@subsubsection=\count185
\c@paragraph=\count186
\c@subparagraph=\count187
\c@figure=\count188
\c@table=\count189
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen138
) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty
Package: inputenc 2021/02/14 v1.3d Input encoding file
\inpenc@prehook=\toks16
\inpenc@posthook=\toks17
) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def
File: l3backend-pdftex.def 2021-07-12 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count190
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box50
) (./output.aux)
\openout1 = `output.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <12> on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <8> on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <6> on input line 10.
[1

{/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./output.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 437 strings out of 478542
 7717 string characters out of 5850413
 299732 words of memory out of 5000000
 18443 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 407070 words of font info for 39 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 34i,6n,41p,150b,191s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
</usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx12.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr12.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr17.pfb>

Output written on output.pdf (1 page, 39062 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 28 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 16 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

What should i do now? How do I fix this?

Comment: there is no error on the Tex log you show.what is the pdf error you get? perhaps show a screenshot of the browser message

Comment: Is this the same problem as https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/648232/pdf-rendering-error?

Comment: (I'm on support staff at Overleaf.) If none of the steps at [Resolving access, loading, and display problems](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Resolving_access%2C_loading%2C_and_display_problems) solve this, please contact us directly with the requested info from that page.